# button position multi screen

Tags: android, button, multiscreen

My problem is very simple.
I have a button that have 100dp marginRight and 100dp marginTop in a xxhdpi density screen.
The problem is, when I change to another density screen or size, the button its not in position I want. It remains the 100dp margin top and right but I don’t won’t this.
I thought that if I use dp, when I change screen it’s was going to be in the position I want, calculate de position in smaller or bigger screens.
I hope you understand, I don’t want to create a layout for every density or size screen.
How can position a button that be in the same position in every screen?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, but it would be helpful to read up on what a dp is http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: My background image have a square. I need the button be inside that square. In xxhdpi if i put 100 dp margin top and right it fix wright. The problem is if I change the screen size, the button its outside the square. I dont know hot to do this for all screens... understand?

Answer (score 0):

on a different screen density that 100dp will change position.
what you can do is support multiple size and create different layout for each.

read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Using the new size qualifiers is a solution.

Comment: My background image have a square. I need the button be inside that square. In xxhdpi if i put 100 dp margin top and right it fix wright. The problem is if I change the screen size, the button its outside the square. I dont know hot to do this for all screens... understand?

Comment: you have to create different layouts for different density read the link that i posted. go to the section of "new size qualifiers". understand?